# Header IMG Not Showing

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why my header background doesn't work! I have tried everything and it doesn't seem to do anything. I would also like the height of the image to be the full height of the image which is 800px;

```css
html {}

header {
  background-image: url(/img/headerbg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Pasajero;
  src: url(/font/Pasajero.otf);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Pasajero;
  src: url(/font/Pasajero.otf);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <h1>DESIGN. DEVELOPMENT. MARKETING</h1>
  <h2>EVERY BUSINESS NEEDS A NEW IDEA...</h2>

</header>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: may be missing quotes url('/img/headerbg.png')

Comment: Check your image file `path`

Answer (score 1):

As per your **HTML** your main.css file inside the css folder and you are linking wrong `url(/img/headerbg.png)`

**Try to Replace**

```
header 
{
    background-image: url(/img/headerbg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

**with this**

```
header 
{  
    background: url(../img/headerbg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: Hello, don't forget to omit '-image' from the style, to read: background: url()...;

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in your CSS, you have use `background` instead of `background-image`. Check updated snippet below.

```css
header {
    background: url(https://dummyimage.com/800x300/ff0000/ffffff.png&text=) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Pasajero;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 300px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: white;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Pasajero;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #f7ff7d; 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>DESIGN. DEVELOPMENT. MARKETING</h1>
    <h2>EVERY BUSINESS NEEDS A NEW IDEA...</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background shorthand is written incorrectly.
Also, note that display: block and position: relative is unnecessary as the header is considered a block element and all nodes are position static by default, which acts very similarly to position relative.

Use the following:

```
header 
{
    background: url(/img/headerbg.png) center center / cover no-repeat;
}
```